# May mod_expire conflict with Wordpress updates?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I would like to use mod_expire for caching content of my Wordpress blog in the user's browser and increase thereby my ranking at YSlow and Google Pagespeed. So I wanted to use a configuration like the one below.

```
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
<FilesMatch ".(ico|jpg|png|gif|css|js|gz)$">
ExpiresDefault A2592000
Header append Cache-Control "private"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

However, the following question arises for me now. What if a plugins code break and the plugin developer publishs an update? I'll download and install it to my blog, but the broken .js-file from the plugin was cached by the user's browser.
Will the users get a broken view of my page until the cache time expires or will they automatically get served the new one from the plugin's update?

Comment: Just curious: why are you disabling ETag?  (ETags would help you solve your problem, no?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is founded: browsers will indeed keep using their the cached (possibly outdated) copy until it expires per your config.

Here is [a helpful summary](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching#LeverageBrowserCaching) of Expires vs. Last-Modified/ETag, including some suggested best practices.

Generally speaking, in your case (since you seem concerned about plugin updates) I'd go with ETag/Last-Modified instead of Expires.

One other idea: you need not bundle js files with all other types.  Just a heuristic but it might help:

```
# can be safely cached
<FilesMatch ".(ico|jpg|png|gif|css|gz)$">
    ExpiresDefault now plus 30 days
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
</FilesMatch>

# don't cache or only cache briefly
<FilesMatch ".js$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    # or: ExpiresDefault now plus 6 hours
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

this script just caches, ico, jpg, png, gif, css, js, gz files not html.
Wordpress will be fine.

if you are having a client side js crash, simply don't cache the js.
Or re run this same again and set js to cache for a short time, like 14400 s.